# How to walk through the OS and generate a hash of every file then output into a txt file?

Tags: python, hash, os.walk, hashlib

so I have this file to walk through the OS and generate a hash of every file using python, however I want it to output the hashes into a txt file. I have tried using:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

But I cannot seem to get this to work all I achieved was printing the last hash into the file. Any advice would be welcomed!

```
import os, hashlib

current_dir = os.getcwd()
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(current_dir):
    for f in files:
        current_file = os.path.join(root,f)
        H = hashlib.md5()

        with open(current_file) as FIN:
            H.update(FIN.read())

        print current_file, H.hexdigest()
```

EDIT: Apologies it seems my explanation was unclear, the above code prints the MD5 values fine however what I am trying to achieve is for the MD5s to be output into a file while also being printed.

EDIT 2:
The complete fully functional code, for people who are stuck in the future (However currently I am receiving a permissions error):

```
import os, hashlib

current_dir = os.getcwd()
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(current_dir):
    for f in files:
        current_file = os.path.join(root,f)
        H = hashlib.md5()

        with open(current_file) as FIN:
            H.update(FIN.read())
            with open("gethashes.txt", "a") as myfile:
                myfile.write(current_file),myfile.write("/n"),myfile.write("            "),myfile.write(H.hexdigest()),myfile.write("%s\n")

    print current_file, H.hexdigest()
```

Comment: Your code, as posted here, has no such problem. Perhaps you are mixing tabs and spaces and thus your indentation is not quite what it seems? Python expands tabs to the next 8th column.

Comment: `from __future__ import print_function` won't do a whole lot- it updates `print` to be a function instead of a keyword; `print "hello"` vs `print("hello")`. Your code as-is doesn't use the print function anyways. (It's mostly a compatibility thing between python2 and python3)

Comment: Apologies guys please see my edit, thanks.

Comment: Do you know how to write to a file in any other context?

Comment: I'm not sure whether you are being condescending or not, however, yes I do know how to I use f=open(.....) then f.write(...) but i can't get it working in this situation.